# Anyway to bind an upload from multi upload box to input file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file-upload, drag-and-drop

I am using the Drag and drop Multi Importer script I [found online](https://github.com/arunkumarsekar/Multiple_file_drag_and_drop_upload), below my div containing the drag and drop is an input type="file"..

Currently if you click the Browse files button from the input and add an image then it shows in the Multi Upload div (and of course the input file section as well)  However not everyone is going to use the browse files button, they are going to drag and drop so is there a way to reverse this behavior?  Where when the client drags a file in the multi upload div it will show in the input file tag as being added?

I hope I wasn't too confusing there.

Here is what I have:

```
<div id="dragAndDropFiles" class="uploadArea">
   <h1>Drop Images Here or Click to Upload</h1>
</div>
 <input type="file" name="thumbnail" id="thumbnail" multiple />

<script type="text/javascript">
var config = {
    support : "image/jpg,image/png,image/bmp,image/jpeg,image/gif", // Valid file formats
    form: "primaryPostForm", // Form ID
    dragArea: "dragAndDropFiles",       // Upload Area ID
}
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    initMultiUploader(config);
    $('.button').click(function () {
        $('#primaryPostForm').submit();
    });

    $('#dragAndDropFiles').bind("click" , function () {
        $('input#thumbnail').click();
    });
});
</script>
```

Ultimately it would be great just to hide the input file type section but still have it in my markup because I have other functions that take that file and create products from it.